# GoogleCloud BigQuery exception handling

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run the following GooleCould's BigQuery:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(site, "=")[OFFSET(1)], r'%\d+', ' ')
    from some_db
    where site = 'something'
    and STARTS_WITH(site, 'XXX')
```

and during the execution I get the following error:

> Array index 1 is out of bounds (overflow)

When I was working with AWS Athena, I used to solve such errors using **try** statements, but I could not find anything equivalent for BigQuery.

How should I handle exceptions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use SAFE_OFFSET instead of OFFSET

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(SPLIT(site, "=")[SAFE_OFFSET(1)], r'%\d+', ' ')
from some_db
where site = 'something'
and STARTS_WITH(site, 'XXX')
```

As of more generic try / catch question  - BigQuery does not have one  - but there is a SAFE prefix that can be used in most functions as SAFE.function_name() - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#safe-prefix

Comment: That actually solved my problem this time,  but my question is more general

Comment: there is no try catch in bigquery. SAFE_OFFSET helps with ARRAY's out of bouns and also there is a SAFE.function_name() prefix that can be use with most of BQ Standard SQL functions.

Comment: the good news is that there is always the way to address specific use case, like in that your specific scenario - so it is not that really bad